# how to include count of icollection to a model using linq c# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have following model:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string City {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Room> Rooms {get;set;}
}

public class Room
{
    public int RoomID {get;set;}
    public bool Decorated {get; set;}
    public int PersonID {get;set;}
    public Person Person {get;set;}
}
```

In Controller I want to include another column count, which counts the decorated rooms allocated to the persons from New York City so that in view count should be accessible: This is what i try! But i get errors

```
var persons = db.Persons.Include(ss => ss.Rooms.Count(pp => pp.Decorated==true)).Where(ww => ww.city == "New York");
```

But I get this error

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

I am new to this! Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just include `Count` to your entity. `Include` method allows you to add navigation properties when retrieving data from db. It means that you should point to the property that refers to another entity. In your case it would be:

```
db.Persons.Include(x => x.Rooms)
```

It will load all `Rooms` that has a reference to `Person` entity. Then you can get the count of the rooms like this:

```
var roomsCount = db.Persons.Include(x => x.Rooms)
    .Where(x => x.PersonID == 12 && x.City == "New York")
    .SelectMany(x => x.Rooms)
    .Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be one of the solutions by using view models

create a ViewModel

```
public class PersonWIthRoomCountViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int DecoratedRoomsAllocated { get; set; }
    }
```

The Controller:

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
    {
        protected StackOverflowAnswersContext db = new StackOverflowAnswersContext();

        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

            Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
            if (person == null)
                return HttpNotFound();

            PersonWIthRoomCountViewModel model = new PersonWIthRoomCountViewModel();

            model.Name = person.Name;
            model.City = person.City;
            var DecoratedRooms = db.Rooms.Where(ww => ww.PersonID == id && ww.Decorated);
            if (DecoratedRooms == null)
            {
                model.DecoratedRoomsAllocated = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                model.DecoratedRoomsAllocated = DecoratedRooms.Count();
            }

            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

The View:

```
@model StackOverflowAnswers.Controllers.PersonWIthRoomCountViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Person Room Count</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.City)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DecoratedRoomsAllocated)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DecoratedRoomsAllocated)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id = Model.PrimaryKey */ }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```